# Spring Integration JMS transaction error channel transaction

Tags: jms, spring-integration

I am currently having difficulties with a JMS transaction in Spring integration. The Integration Flow that I am creating is the following:

JMS queue A -> publish/subscribe channel (sync) -> JMS queue B and JMS queue C

I want guaranteed delivery of the message on JMS queue B and JMS queue C. However to make it slightly more difficult I want to store the messages that result in an error on a seperate JMQ queue and acknowledge the message on queue A.

However if I test this and throw an error before the message has been set on queue C (let's assume queue B is done first and queue C second) the transaction will acknowledge queue A and commit both the message on queue B and on the error queue.

How should I tell spring integration to not commit the message on queue B when an error occurs and only acknowledge A and commit the error queue?

Starting a new transaction for B and C will not work because then the acknowledge on A could fail after B and C are committed.

Answer (score 0):

For me that looks like you are going to acknowledge A independently of the result for B and C. So, frankly: how about to have those separate transactions, but acknowledge A before the start for the second one. And in this case rollback for B and C and send to the `error-channel` won't affect A.

Comment: But then the message could be lost if the second transaction is rolled back and an error occurs while writing the message to the JMS error channel. Since A was already acknowledged upon arrival the message is lost..

Comment: OK. How about to take a look to the `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` for A? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19717-01/819-7757/aeqeg/index.html